# Required only SharePoint 2013 Skydive feature

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

i have installed SharePoint 2013 sky drive on my POC server it works fine.
My business requirement is to enable only skydive option, it means we have to disable **News Feed** and **Sites** feature on every body's My-Site .

Is there any possibility to disable these 2 features by some configuration?